# Continuity and Differentiability of a function

Tags: derivatives

If $f(x) = ae^{ax}$ for $x \le 0$; $f(x) = x^2 + 4x + 2b$ for $x > 0$ and $g(x) = \sin |bx + a - 2|$. It is given that both $f$ and $g$ are differentiable at $x = 0$. Then $g(x)$ is not differentiable for which value of $x$?
The options are
(A) $\pi$
(B) $-4$
(C) $\frac{\pi}{4}$
(D) $4$

I found out that $a = 2$ and $b = 1$, but can't proceed further.

Comment: When $a=2, b=1$, I don't think that $g(x) = \sin |x|$ is differentiable at $x=0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, I don't think that $a=2$ and $b=1$. It seems that you have the right idea to find $a$ and $b$, however.

For $f$ to be differentiable at $x=0$, it must be continuous as well. Therefore $ae^{a(0)} = (0)^2+4(0)+2b$, leading to $a=2b$. To be differentiable at $x=0$ it must be that $a^2e^{a(0)} = 2(0)+4$, leading to $a^2 = 4$. This means that $a=2$ and $b=1$ or $a=-2$ and $b=-1$.

Now we look at the differentiability of $g$. For $g$ to be differentiable at $x=0$, $|bx-a-2|$ must be differentiable at $x=0$ (by chain rule). If $a=2, b=1$ then this is $|x|$ which is not differentiable at $x=0$. Otherwise if $a=-2, b=-1$, then this is $|-x-4|$, which is differentiable at $x=0$.

Hint: To find where $g$ is not differentiable try to find where $|-x-4|$ is not differentiable.

Comment: I missed out the negative values. Thank you @Mosquite